# slick not joining when explicitly writing a join query

Tags: scala, slick

```scala
    val query = Foo
      .join(Bar)
      .on(_.fooId === _.id)
      .filter { case (foo, bar) =>
        foo.someId === 666 && bar.status === 1
      }
      .map { case (_, bar) => (bar.id, bar.name) }
      .take(1)
```

This code turns into sql statement as follows:

```sql
select x2.`id`, x2.`name` 
from `Bar` x3, `Foo` x2 
where ((x3.`someId` = 666) and (x2.`status` = 1)) and (x3.`fooId` = x2.`id`) 
limit 1
```

As slick's doc says(https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.0/sql-to-slick.html#explicit-inner-joins), the syntax `join` and `on` produce explicit join query. So What is going on here?

Comment: We can safely conclude the docs are wrong here (https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1716 https://groups.google.com/g/scalaquery/c/1v78rdy8DY0/m/K3QR5LQYBwAJ). Instead I believe Slick queries compile to implicit joins when possible, explicit otherwise (https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/main/doc/src/queries.md#monadic-joins-indexjoinmonadic-monadicjoin-joininner-innerjoin-joincross-crossjoin-joinimplicit-implicitjoin-joinexplicit-explicitjoin)

Comment: The result is the same, but the performance for explicit join seems different from implicit one? @Raf

Comment: I believe it might differ, depending on which DB you use. You should `EXPLAIN` both queries and see their execution plan to be sure

Comment: I have tried to explain it, and it turns out the result is the same, which use the same keys and both use temporary. But this conclusion maybe true just under this case. Need to learn more about the mechanism of `join` and `where` in mysql. @Raf